# How can I give a label to an array index in order to call it?

Tags: python-3.x

Let's say I have `multiple arrays X` of `size Y` forming a Matrix of `size Matrix[X,Y]`. Instead of calling each `array X` with its number `Matrix[1,:]` for my second array for instance, I would like it to be called as `Matrix['label',:]` instead.

Is it feasible with `numpy` or `pytorch`? Thank you for the help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a library for that.

```
data = {"row1": [1, 2, 3],
        "row2": [4, 5, 6],
        "row3": [7, 8, 9]}
print(data["row1"][2])  # prints 3
print(data["row2"][1])  # prints 5
```